# Countdown Reverse Counter

Tags: android, reverse, countdown, countdowntimer

**Update**

This has been solved. What i have done is this :-

```
sec = (time/1000)%60;

            if (sec == 0){
                min++;
                if (min > 59){
                    min = 0;
                    hour++;
                }
```

and then set the min = -1 so that the initial 0 will not add min to timer.

---

I need to have a counter which starts from 0 to infinite time till user selects an options.

So, what I have done is implement a CountDownTimer  with some logic so that I can achieve what I wanted.

So, I took 6 hour as maximum time till when the timer will go on. 
But the issue I am getting is once the seconds reach 59, then it reset to 0 as I programmed it, but then it stays 0 and the min start increasing as per seconds. Please Help

Here's my Code :-

```
public void newCountTimer(){
    countdowntimer = new CountDownTimer(21600000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long time = 21600000 - millisUntilFinished;
            sec = time/1000;
            if (sec > 59){
                sec = 0;
                min++;
                if (min > 59){
                    min = 0;
                    hour++;
                }
            }
            if (sec < 10) {
                if (min < 10) {
                    if (hour < 10) {
                        timer_box.setText("0" + hour + ":0" + min + ":0" + sec);
                    } else {
                        timer_box.setText("" + hour + ":0" + min + ":0" + sec);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (hour < 10) {
                        timer_box.setText("0" + hour + ":" + min + ":0" + sec);
                    } else {
                        timer_box.setText("" + hour + ":" + min + ":0" + sec);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (min < 10) {
                    if (hour < 10) {
                        timer_box.setText("0" + hour + ":0" + min + ":" + sec);
                    } else {
                        timer_box.setText("" + hour + ":0" + min + ":" + sec);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (hour < 10) {
                        timer_box.setText("0" + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
                    } else {
                        timer_box.setText("" + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: I suggest to use Calendar class so you don't have to do all format textlike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `sec` variable will always be getting higher and higher

```
 sec = time/1000;
            if (sec > 59){
```

So sec will go from 59 to 60 to 61 to 62 and so on, and therefore always be greater than 59. Always increasing causing min to always increase after 1 minute

My suggestion is to add a mod 60 to your `sec` calculation

```
  sec = (time/1000)%60;
            if (sec == 0){
                min++; 
   ...
```